# Babel 6 + React - Passing initial data (In-browser transpiler)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, symfony, babeljs

I`m using React + Babel 6, with webpack. 
When I was using Babel 5, it was easy to pass in the initial data using a script type="text/babel" on the page, then babel-core/browser.js takes care of it.

But now, using Babel 6, I have to load all the initial data calling the REST API, as my component mounts.

This results in the browser client **opening a connection** on the server to render the frontend, and then the frontend opens a **new connection** to get the data.

Wouldn't this affect my server performance as, now I have 2 connections vs the older 1 connection oppened?

**EDIT:**

I wish I could keep using the folowing snippet on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('app/bundle.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/babel"> 
    var jsonVar = '{vars}';

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App vars={vars}/>,
        document.getElementById('app-wrapper')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: What's the relation to Symfony3?

Comment: I'm using Symfony3 to render this parametes. If I wasn`t, i could just render the template server-side with this variables. Yes, I know there is some hacks using Proccess and nodejs, to do it in Symfony too; but its hackish.

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal pattern to load your server side content and, then, your components grab some data. One downside of this design, of course, is that  this implies one initial render **plus** api request for data.

However, you can setup a server side render with react components, rendering initial data on the server. If your backend is nodejs, for instance, you can use [ReactDOMServer.renderToString](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostring).

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using renderTOString! For sure it will be usefui!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by:
Using an "application/json" script tag(passing an id) and put serialized data inside it.

```
<script type="application/json" id="app-data"> { "id" : 1 } </script>
```

Then in the app.js:

```
var appData =  JSON.parse( document.getElementById(script-id).innerHTML )
```